# Postgres query records where any element in array of objects in JSONB field contains number > or < x

Tags: arrays, postgresql, object, compare, jsonb

I've searched around but this seems to be a more unique requirement for querying JSONB fields than is common and haven't found a solution yet.
My table has a jsonb field called 'plan', the content of which looks like this:

```
{
    days: [
        {
            summary: {
                total: 100
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

There could be potentially infinity day objects inside the days array. Is it possible to run a query that selects all rows where 'total' is greater than or less than a given number in at least one of the day objects?

If necessary I can rearrange the table or take the 'summary' data and put it in a postgres array field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can fetch all rows with `total` in your jsonb column `plan` not equal to, say 101, as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table t,
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(plan->'days') days
WHERE
    (days->'summary'->>'total')::integer != 101;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already worked it out by moving the summaries to an ARRAY[] row, but this might have been a much simpler fix. I'll try it sometime.